# Bootstrap 3 Drop Up Menu with sub-menus

Tags: html, css, drop-down-menu, jquery-plugins, twitter-bootstrap-3

The html, css and javascript shown below is working flawlessly with Bootstrap 3.3.4 using jquery 1.9.1.js. When it's placed in a page running Bootstrap 3.0.0 using query 1.10.2.js, the menu opens, but when the item with sub-menus is clicked the menu collapses. Any suggestions? Thanks.

HTML

> ```
>   <div class="col-sm-4">          <h3 class="header-title">Navigation</h3>
>       <span class="line"></span>      <div class="dropup m-b">            <button
> ```
>
> class="btn btn-success" type="button" data-toggle="dropdown">         Menu
>
> Action
>
> Another action     
>         Dropdown header
>
> Sub action
>
> Another sub action
>
> Something else here
>
> Something else here
>
> Separated link

CSS

> .dropdown-submenu > a:after {   content: "";   float: right;
>   margin-right: -10px; } @media (min-width: 768px) {   .dropdown-submenu
>   {
>       position: relative;   }   .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
>       top: 0;
>       left: 100%;
>       margin-top: -6px;
>       border-top-left-radius: 0;   }   .dropup .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu,   .navbar-fixed-bottom .dropdown-submenu
>   .dropdown-menu {
>       top: auto;
>       bottom: 0;
>       margin-top: 0;
>       margin-bottom: -6px;
>       border-top-left-radius: 4px;
>       border-bottom-left-radius: 0;   }   .dropdown-menu-right .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
>       left: auto;
>       right: 100%;
>       border-top-left-radius: 4px;
>       border-top-right-radius: 0;   }   .dropup .dropdown-menu-right .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu,   .navbar-fixed-bottom
>   .dropdown-menu-right .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
>       border-radius: 4px 4px 0;   }   .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
>       margin-top: 6px;
>       border-left: 4px dashed;
>       border-top: 4px solid transparent;
>       border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;   }   .dropdown-menu-right .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
>       float: left;
>       border-left: none;
>       margin-left: -10px;
>       margin-right: 0;
>       border-right: 4px dashed;
>       border-top: 4px solid transparent;
>       border-bottom: 4px solid transparent;   } } @media (max-width: 767px) {   .dropdown-submenu .dropdown-menu {
>       position: static;
>       margin-top: 0;
>       border: 0;
>       box-shadow: none;   }   .dropdown-submenu > a:after {
>       margin-top: 8px;
>       border-top: 4px dashed;
>       border-left: 4px solid transparent;
>       border-right: 4px solid transparent;   }   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu >
>   li.dropdown-header,   .dropup > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu >
>   .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu >
>   .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropdown >
>   .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > a,
>   .dropup > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li >
>   a,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu
>
> > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 30px;   }   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu >
> >     li.dropdown-header,   .dropup > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,
> >     .btn-group > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li
> >     .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a,
> >     .dropup > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 40px;   }   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropup > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a,   .dropup > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 50px;   }   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropup >
> >     .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu >
> >     li.dropdown-header,   .btn-group > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .dropdown > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a,   .dropup >
> >     .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a,
> >     .btn-group > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 60px;   }   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 35px;   }   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu >
> >     .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 45px;   }   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,   .navbar-nav > .dropdown >
> >     .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 55px;   }   .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li.dropdown-header,
> >     .navbar-nav > .dropdown > .dropdown-menu > .dropdown-submenu >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li > .dropdown-menu > li >
> >     .dropdown-menu > li > a {
> >         padding-left: 65px;   } }

jQuery

> 'use strict';
>
> (function(factory) {   if (typeof define == 'function' && define.amd)
>   {
>       // AMD. Register as an anonymous module
>       define(['jquery'], factory);   }   else if (typeof exports == 'object') {
>       // Node/CommonJS
>       module.exports = factory(require('jquery'));   }   else {
>       // Browser globals
>       factory(jQuery);   } })(function($) {   var desc = ':not(.disabled, .divider, .dropdown-header)';
>
> function Submenupicker(element) {
>       this.$element = $(element);
>       this.$main = this.$element.closest('.dropdown, .dropup, .btn-group');
>       this.$menu = this.$element.parent();
>       this.$drop = this.$menu.parent().parent();
>       this.$menus = this.$menu.siblings('.dropdown-submenu');
>
> ```
> var $children = this.$menu.find('> .dropdown-menu > ' + desc);
>
> this.$submenus = $children.filter('.dropdown-submenu');
> this.$items = $children.not('.dropdown-submenu');
>
> this.init();   }
> ```
>
> Submenupicker.prototype = {
>       init: function() {
>         this.$element.on('click.bs.dropdown', this.click.bind(this));
>         this.$element.keydown(this.keydown.bind(this));
>         this.$menu.on('hide.bs.submenu', this.hide.bind(this));
>         this.$items.keydown(this.item_keydown.bind(this));
>
> ```
>   // Bootstrap fix
>   this.$menu.nextAll(desc + ':first:not(.dropdown-submenu)').children('a').keydown(this.next_keydown.bind(this));
> },
> click: function(event) {
>   event.stopPropagation();
>
>   this.toggle();
> },
> toggle: function() {
>   if (this.$menu.hasClass('open')) {
>     this.close();
>   }
>   else {
>     this.$menu.addClass('open');
>     this.$menus.trigger('hide.bs.submenu');
>   }
> },
> hide: function(event) {
>   // Stop event bubbling
>   event.stopPropagation();
>
>   this.close();
> },
> close: function() {
>   this.$menu.removeClass('open');
>   this.$submenus.trigger('hide.bs.submenu');
> },
> keydown: function(event) {
>   // 13: Return, 27: Esc, 32: Spacebar
>   // 38: Arrow up, 40: Arrow down
>
>   // Off vertical scrolling
>   if (/^(32|38|40)$/.test(event.keyCode)) {
>     event.preventDefault();
>   }
>
>   if (/^(13|32)$/.test(event.keyCode)) {
>     this.toggle();
>   }
>   else if (/^(27|38|40)$/.test(event.keyCode)) {
>     event.stopPropagation();
>
>     if (event.keyCode == 27) {
>       if (this.$menu.hasClass('open')) {
>         this.close();
>       }
>       else {
>         this.$menus.trigger('hide.bs.submenu');
>         this.$drop.removeClass('open').children('a').focus();
>       }
>     }
>     else {
>       var $items = this.$main.find('li:not(.disabled):visible > a');
>
>       var index = $items.index(event.target);
>
>       if (event.keyCode == 38 && index !== 0) {
>         index--;
>       }
>       else if (event.keyCode == 40 && index !== $items.length - 1) {
>         index++;
>       }
>       else {
>         return;
>       }
>
>       $items.eq(index).focus();
>     }
>   }
> },
> item_keydown: function(event) {
>   // 27: Esc
>
>   if (event.keyCode != 27) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   event.stopPropagation();
>
>   this.close();
>   this.$element.focus();
> },
> next_keydown: function(event) {
>   // 38: Arrow up
>
>   if (event.keyCode != 38) {
>     return;
>   }
>
>   // Off vertical scrolling
>   event.preventDefault();
>
>   event.stopPropagation();
>
>   // Use this.$drop instead this.$main (optimally)
>   var $items = this.$drop.find('li:not(.disabled):visible > a');
>
>   var index = $items.index(event.target);
>
>   $items.eq(index - 1).focus();
> }   };
> ```
>
> // For AMD/Node/CommonJS used elements (optional)   //
>   http://learn.jquery.com/jquery-ui/environments/amd/   return
>   ($.fn.submenupicker = function(elements) {
>       var $elements = this instanceof $ ? this : $(elements);
>
> ```
> return $elements.each(function() {
>   var data = $.data(this, 'bs.submenu');
>
>   if (!data) {
>     data = new Submenupicker(this);
>
>     $.data(this, 'bs.submenu', data);
>   }
> });   }); });
> ```

Comment: could you try to sort out your code formatting - its pretty impossible to read. try using [dirtymarkup](http://dirtymarkup.com) and then indenting by four spaces to create code blocks.

Answer (score 0):

Figured out what was wrong. I'd failed to put the script in. Here it is in case anyone wants to try this.

> $('.dropdown-submenu > a').submenupicker();